# Find third last event in table - Incomplete output

Tags: sql, firebird

As my research into Firebird continues, I've attempted to improve some of my queries. As I use Libreoffice Base, I'm not 100% sure how the data entry code works, but I believe it's something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "Data Entry"(
  ID int,
  Date date,
  "Vehicle Type" varchar,
  events int,
  "Hours 1" int,
  "Hours 2" int
);

INSERT INTO "Data Entry" VALUES
(1, '31/12/22', 'A', '1', '0', '1'),
(2, '31/12/22', 'A', '1', '0', '1'),
(3, '29/12/22', 'A', '3', '0', '1'),
(4, '25/06/22', 'B1', '1', '0', '1'),
(5, '24/06/22' , 'B1', '1', '1', '0'),
(6, '24/06/22' , 'B1', '1', '1', '0'),
(7, '31/12/22' , 'B2', '7', '0', '1'),
(8, '29/12/22' , 'C', '1', '0', '1'),
(9, '29/12/22' , 'C', '2', '0', '1'),
(10, '19/01/22' , 'D1', '5', '1', '0'),
(11, '23/01/22' , 'D2', '6', '1', '1'),
(12, '29/07/19' , 'D3', '5', '0', '1'),
(13, '21/12/22' , 'D4', '1', '0', '1'),
(14, '19/12/22' , 'D4', '1', '1', '1'),
(15, '19/12/22' , 'D4', '1', '0', '1'),
(16, '28/12/22' , 'E', '2', '0', '1'),
(17, '24/12/22' , 'E', '3', '0', '1'),
(18, '14/07/07' , '1', '0', '0', '1'),
(19, '22/12/22' , '2', '1', '0', '1');
```

I tried this through the online Fiddle pages, but it throws up errors, so either I'm doing it incorrectly, or it's because there was no option for Firebird. Hopefully irrelevant, as I have the table already through the front-end.

One of my earlier queries which works as expected is shown below, along with its output:

```
SELECT
    "Vehicle Type",
    DATEDIFF(DAY, "Date", CURRENT_DATE) AS "Days Since 3rd Last Event"
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            "Date",
            "Events",
            "Vehicle Type",
            "Event Count",
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "Vehicle Type" ORDER BY "Date" DESC) AS "rn"
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    "Date",
                    "Events",
                    "Vehicle Type",
                    SUM("Events") OVER (PARTITION BY "Vehicle Type" ORDER BY "Date" DESC) AS "Event Count"
                FROM "Data Entry"
            )
        WHERE "Event Count" >= 3
    )
WHERE "rn" = 1
```

| Vehicle Type | Days Since 3rd Last Event |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B1 | 191 |
| B2 | 1 |
| C | 3 |
| D1 | 347 |
| D2 | 343 |
| D3 | 1252 |
| D4 | 14 |
| E | 8 |

In this output, it does not list every vehicle because not all vehicles have an `Event Count` that is equal to or greater than 3. The new query I am trying to put together is a combination of different queries (omitted to keep things relevant, plus they already work on their own), with a rewrite of the above code as well:

```
SELECT
    "Vehicle Type",
    SUM("Hours 1" + "Hours 2") AS "Total Hours",
    MAX(CASE
            WHEN
                "Total Events" = 3
            THEN
                DATEDIFF(DAY, "Date", CURRENT_DATE)
        END
    ) "Days Since 3rd Last Event"
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            "Vehicle Type",
            "Date",
            "Hours 1",
            "Hours 2",
            CASE
                WHEN
                    "Events" > 0
                THEN
                    SUM(    "Events")
                OVER(
                    PARTITION BY "Vehicle Type"
                    ORDER BY "Date" DESC
                )
            END
            "Total Events"
        FROM
            "Data Entry"
    )
GROUP BY "Vehicle Type"
ORDER BY "Vehicle Type"
```

The expected output should be:

| Vehicle Type | Days Since 3rd Last Event | Total Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 1 |
| 2 |  | 1 |
| A | 3 | 3 |
| B1 | 191 | 3 |
| B2 | 1 | 1 |
| C | 3 | 2 |
| D1 | 347 | 1 |
| D2 | 343 | 2 |
| D3 | 1252 | 1 |
| D4 | 14 | 4 |
| E | 8 | 2 |

However, the actual output is:

| Vehicle Type | Days Since 3rd Last Event | Total Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 1 |
| 2 |  | 1 |
| A |  | 3 |
| B1 | 191 | 3 |
| B2 |  | 1 |
| C | 3 | 2 |
| D1 |  | 1 |
| D2 |  | 2 |
| D3 |  | 1 |
| D4 | 14 | 4 |
| E |  | 2 |

Granted, I've mixed and matched code, made some up myself, and copied some parts from elsewhere online, so there's a good chance I've not understood something correctly and blindly added it in thinking it would work, but now I'm at a loss as to what that could be. I've had a play around with changing the values of the `WHEN` statements and altering the operators between `=`, `>`, and `>=`, but any deviation from what's currently shown above outputs incorrect numbers. At least the three numbers displayed in the actual output are correct.

Comment: Can you update your post with sample data, current output and expected output?

Comment: Is there a way for me to upload a sample .odb file? Not sure how else to do it

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: I couldn't get the online pages to work, so I've added the data entry to the bottom of my question. Will edit the expected output shortly

Comment: Edits complete. Moved the content around in my question to hopefully improve readability as well

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/ has options for Firebird, but the problem is that your insert statement is invalid. Firebird doesn't support a multi-row values clause.

Comment: A Fiddle of your attempt: https://dbfiddle.uk/vQvJ6ubh

Answer (score 0):

You could try using two rankings:

- the first one that catches last three rows
- the second one that catches your last row among the possible three

then get your date differences.

```
WITH last_three AS (
    SELECT "Vehicle Type", "Date", 
           SUM("Hours 1"+"Hours 2") OVER(PARTITION BY "Vehicle Type") AS "Total Hours",
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "Vehicle Type" ORDER BY "Date" DESC) AS rn 
    FROM "Data Entry"
), last_third AS (
    SELECT "Vehicle Type", "Date", "Total Hours",
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "Vehicle Type" ORDER BY rn DESC) AS rn2
    FROM last_three
    WHERE rn <= 3
) 
SELECT "Vehicle Type", 
       DATEDIFF(DAY, "Date", CURRENT_DATE) AS "Days Since 3rd Last Event",
       "Total Hours"
FROM last_third 
WHERE rn2 = 1
ORDER BY "Vehicle Type"
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/KDcew2Ue).

**Note**: You will get values for the "*Vehicle Type*" 1 and 2 too. If you can explain the rationale behind having those values empty, this query can be tweaked accordingly.

Comment: Due to many different queries running simultaneously in a form I've designed, I want to combine them to improve readability, as they currently output data individually, rather than all in one go. One of those other queries was to sum up the total hours each vehicle type is in service. That hourly summary outputs all vehicle types. The intent with this question was to essentially tack the 3rd event query to the end of the hourly summary. I've edited the new code in the question to reflect "Hours 1" and "Hours 2" that are also obtained from "Data Entry". (I promise this is the last time I edit!)

Comment: How do you compute total hours? Can you update your post with values too for cross checking? It'll also avoid going back and forth due to misunderstandings.

Comment: The total hours are a sum of the `Hours 1` and `Hours 2` columns for each row, which is then grouped by `Vehicle Type` for a total amount of hours on each type. I've added the appropriate table structure and data entry into the first code sample, updated the outputs to show the expected values, and the code I'm trying to get working has the sum line in the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: It's enough to add a `SUM` window function over the sum of both "Hours 1" and "Hours 2" in the first subquery, then keeping it in the selection scope for successive subqueries.

Comment: I have a few other queries I plan to combine into this one larger query, so keeping the columns separate would keep my options open. I haven't mentioned them in this question as they are currently irrelevant, and I can figure out how to do those ones myself. Plus, I don't want to have more of an information overload than there already is in this question.

Comment: Consider posting another question if merging those queries is still a problem for you.

Comment: The merging works. However, there is a discrepancy in output with your code and my old code. In mine, the 3rd event check counts backward from when the query is run, and adds up the events for each vehicle type until it reaches 3. It then uses the date from the corresponding row to count days since that third event. In your code, it looks like it counts the third last row matching the vehicle type instead.

Comment: The two `ROW_NUMBER` functions are only used in combination to get the third row, of the last if there are less than 3 rows, and make the difference in dates.

Comment: I think in that case it could be that some of the rows in my actual database have an entry of 0, which causes the confusion, correct?